# same origin restriction blocking font from same origin

Tags: html, css, cors

[This](http://spintires.com/) website uses a font hosted on the same origin (http://www.spintires.com/assets/landing/css/communist.ttf). However, Chrome reports that they are considering blocking cross origin fonts, and firefox already blocks it.

Webkit throws this error:

> Blink is considering rejecting non spec-compliant cross-origin web font requests: http://www.spintires.com/assets/landing/css/communist.ttf.
>   Please use Access-Control-Allow-Origin to make these requests spec-compliant.

I do not have any access to the server, and I am not asking this to fix the problem (although I might report a solution to the crew) but this is more for educational purposes, as I have no idea why this resource is blocked, because the headers look almost exactly the same to the ones of a picture and the html document, and the origin is the same.

Another thing I noticed was that Chrome loads the file unsuccessfully and requests a partial content after that (and right now it also does a full request after the first one failing).

TL;DR;
Why do browsers report/block the loading of a font file which originates from a seemingly the **'same'** origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the same origin. You're loading `spintires.com` and the web font is hosted on `www.spintires.com`. Those are different origins (even though they point to the same place).

You can verify this by opening [www.spintires.com](http://www.spintires.com) instead of [spintires.com](http://spintires.com) (only the second one will throw the error).

Comment: That was an easy find. Have looked over it. And this would mean the issue could be solved by removing the `www.` from the stylesheet link, right?

Comment: No, removing the `www` would simply create a different problem: you'd get an error when visiting `www.spintires.com` instead of getting an error when visiting `spintires.com`. The proper solution would be to add CORS headers to your web fonts (you can find plenty of articles on how to do this by searching for `web fonts cors`). Another quick solution would be to dynamically set the web font URL to either with or without `www` depending on the request's host.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, serving webfonts from AWS likely won't work in Firefox and IE 9+ because AWS doesn't support the Access-Control-Origin-Header. See this [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=34281&start=100&tstart=0) on the AWS forums. Seems to be a problem for a lot of people.

As an alternative to AWS, Google's cloud services support cross-origin file serving. I just set up a bucket to serve webfonts, and it seems to be working. See this [blog](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/03/google-cloud-storage-adds-several.html) post and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am however not looking to any alternative, and how do you come to the conclusion this site uses AWS? The only thing I am asking is why the browser **blocks** a request from an origin that seems the same (but there should be a difference, else it won't throw this error, right?).

Comment: Regarding serving fonts from S3, I recently started to get the "Blink is considering rejecting..." message after upgrading to Chrome 36, I was able to fix the problem by enabling CORS on my bucket.  See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=396899#396899 for the configuration example.

Answer (score 2):

Download this file communist.ttf and put it on your server.

Comment: Quoted from my question: "I do not have any access to the server" and what it looks like on the client: "the origin is the same". I am looking for an explanation **why** browsers report/block this request which is from the **same** origin. So basically it already is on the same server I guess.